# No output for the following code

Tags: bash, if-statement

the code is:

```
echo -n "Enter the number you want to search for"
read number1
for i in `seq 1 $N`
do
  temp= $number1
  if [ temp -eq ${array[$index]} ]
  then 
    temp= $index
  fi
done

echo " The position is" $temp
```

i donot get an output for this 
just the position is and no number.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Insert `set -eu` at the top of the code and see if you get some error messages. This will help you in many other situations, too.

Comment: $N is the length of an array. I am looking whether the input number is present in the array or not

Comment: for i in ${array[@]}
do

  if [[ $i == $number1 ]]

then

   temp= $i

fi

done

this is a simpler version of the code, but i even want the position of the element in the array. Number1 is an input from the user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few big problems here.

**Whitespace in assignment.** One problem is that these lines:

```
  temp= $number1

    temp= $index
```

need to be like this instead:

```
  temp=$number1

    temp=$index
```

This is because in Bash, something like this:

```
varname=value command
```

runs the command `command` with the environment variable `varname` set to `value`. In your case, this:

```
temp= $number1
```

tries to run the command `$number1` with the environment variable `temp` set to the empty string.

**Reuse of temporary variable.** Another problem is that this line:

```
  temp=$number1
```

is run on every pass through the loop; so even if `temp` had previously been set to an appropriate array index, the above will discard that value and replace it with the number that the user had entered. Really, you should just remove this line, and use `$number1` directly when you need it.

**Variable-name mismatch.** Another problem is that this line:

```
for i in `seq 1 $N`
```

uses `i` for the loop variable, but these lines:

```
  if [ temp -eq ${array[$index]} ]
  then 
    temp= $index
```

use `index`. Needless to say, these need to match.

**Unexpanded variable.** This line:

```
  if [ temp -eq ${array[$i]} ]
```

was surely meant to be this:

```
  if [ $temp -eq ${array[$i]} ]
```

(expanding the variable `$temp` instead of using the string `'temp'`); but in light of the above, it should now be:

```
  if [ $number1 -eq ${array[$i]} ]
```

**Array indices.** Array indices start at zero; so if *N* is the number of elements in the array, then you need to iterate from 0 to *N*-1. So, this:

```
for i in `seq 1 $N`
```

needs to be this:

```
for i in `seq 0 $((N - 1))`
```

Though I actually think you should get rid of `N` entirely, and use `${#array[@]}` (which is a Bash notation meaning "the number of elements in `array`) instead:

```
for i in `seq 0 $((${#array[@]} - 1))`
```